# How can I copy data using transactions between two multitenant datasources?

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection, multi-tenant

I've managed to set up multitenancy datasource using [article](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-5-multitenancy). As a result I have two connections, which I can get by

```
MultiTenantConnectionProvider provider = ctx.getBean(MapMultitenantConnectionProvider.class);

Connection main = provider.getConnection("main");
Connection alt = provider.getConnection("alt");
```

Both of these connections are PgConnection.class type (Connection interface), and support transaction management and all the stuff that I need. But I also need to pass enough big data from the first connection to another without analysis or any data filtering.

I've managed to iterate a ResultSet, achieved by

```
String getCompaniesQuery = "select * from companies";
String setRecordQuery = "insert into companies (company) values (?)";

try (Connection main = provider.getConnection("main");
     Connection alt = provider.getConnection("alt")) {

    PreparedStatement companies = main.prepareStatement(getCompaniesQuery);
    ResultSet set = companies.executeQuery();

    while (set.next()) {

        PreparedStatement records = alt.prepareStatement(setRecordQuery);
        records.setString(1, set.getString(1));

        records.execute();
        alt.commit();
    }            

} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but this iteration makes me feel unhappy.

Advice me please, or point me the direction (or framework) to an efficient way of operation (maybe using streams and lambdas) rather than manual iteration of result sets to pass data from alt to main (mentioned connections)?

The structure of all tables in databases is equal.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what clever things you do with streams or lambdas or ORM mappings ... under the hood will be SQL select and insert statements.   And iteration of resultsets.

If you want to transfer data without using SQL select / insert / iteration, then you need to look for DB-specific support for copying or syncing data between databases.

For example, with Oracle you could use something like:

```
INSERT into local_table select * from table@database_link;
```

or

```
/* SQLPlus */
COPY FROM database TO database CREATE destination_table
     [(column, column, column, ...)] USING query
```

where database has the form `username[/password]@connect_identifier`.

(source: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9532217300346683472)

Comment: It's a pitty, but this is not my case. My current goal is to use java as a data maintenance manager between databases... Also, i use multitenance datasources, because need to operate between separate database servers...

Comment: If you want to be general (database independent), you must restrict yourself to standard SQL.